# run a script if error prevents running any other script

Tags: permissions, scripts

Because of sync issues, my bash scripts sometimes lose run permissions.

I have scripts hooked up to keyboard shortcuts, and sometimes I'm not sure if there's a lack of response from the shortcut because I've lost permissions, or I just haven't set that particular keyboard shortcut.

I'd like to be able to run a specific script, like "yad --text="sorry, lost permissions" if any
script execution gets denied due to permission failure (or whatever, maybe even get a report of what the error was)

Is this possible?

P.S. yad is a bash dialog program like Zenity but *way better*

Comment: No. No process keeps track of "file execution failures because of permissions". You might be able to modify the `command-not-found` package, or simply `chmod 755` the scripts after the `sync`, issues or not. The best way is to resolve the "sync issues" (and "`sync`" in Linux/Unix has a specific meaning, and is not applicable to your situation. Do you mean backup/restore, NFS, VM, or what?)

Comment: I don't need the script to fire only if a script fails due to that reason, but just if it fails for any reason at all.  The script I would run is one that restores my permissions.  By sync I mean using syncthing, syncting between multiple computers.  Is there some log file where a script run failure would be recorded?  I could monitor that folder using inotify-wait.

Comment: p.s. all my keyboard shortcuts are done by Kupfer (keyboard launcher).  Is there a way to run kupfer so as to redirect all errors to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper script that checks the exit code and runs `yad` if needed.

Comment: I googled wrappers, but it seemed to only apply to exit codes (could be wrong though).  I'm currently trying a bash trap, like from here: https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/the-bash-trap-trap-ce6083f36700

Comment: Oh, do you get some signal with the permission failure?

Comment: no, the process is an ongoing one (the launcher application "Kupfer" which is where I keep all my keyboard shortcuts) and so there is no exit code.  If I ran kupfer in a terminal there would be an error code that spits out at the time of the shortcut execution but the process continues on from there.